# Add hot link image to email body

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

How to add hot link image to email body?

What I want is "When click on image, it should direct to a url"> image itself should work as a link.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the receiving email client supports html rendering you can perform this in html.

```
<a href="http://link.com"><img src="http://linktoimg.com/img.jpg" /></a>
```